# How to install PECL extensions on ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl, id3

I'm really new to Ubuntu I wanted to use the PECL id3 package so I shifted from Windows to Ubuntu.

I installed php5, apache2, libcurl, php5-dev, php-pear but when I try to install the php_http extension it is giving an error. It asked for zlib and libcurl and I just hit return key to select the default  then this happens with an error at the end:

```
maniteja@maniteja:~$ sudo pecl install pecl_http
downloading pecl_http-2.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-2.0.4.tgz (152,350 bytes)
.....done: 152,350 bytes
64 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Enable extended HTTP support [yes] : 
where to find zlib [/usr] : 
where to find libcurl [/usr] : 
where to find libevent [/usr] : 
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr     --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no 
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable extended HTTP support... yes, shared
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getdomainname... yes
checking for getservbyport... yes  
checking for getservbyport_r... yes
checking for getservbyname... yes
checking for getservbyname_r... yes
checking for zlib.h... found in /usr
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.7
checking for curl/curl.h... found in /usr
checking for curl-config... found: /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for curl version >= 7.18.2... 7.29.0
checking for SSL support in libcurl... yes
checking for openssl support in libcurl... no
checking for gnutls support in libcurl... no
checking for bundled SSL CA info... /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
checking for event2/event.h... not found
configure: WARNING: continuing without libevent support
checking for ext/raphf support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic    library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so:   undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line in Unknown on line 0
no
    checking for ext/propro support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic    library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line in Unknown on line 0
no
checking whether to depend on extensions which have been built shared... yes
checking for ext/hash support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line in Unknown on line 0
yes
checking for php_hash.h... /usr/include/php5/ext/hash
checking for ext/json support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line in Unknown on line 0
yes
checking for ext/iconv support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line in Unknown on line 0
yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/hash... yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/iconv... yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/json... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format...     func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC 
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared   libraries...     yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
        /bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/libtool     --mode=compile   cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php5/ext/hash  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/php_http_buffer.c -o php_http_buffer.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php5/ext/hash -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/php_http_buffer.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_http_buffer.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php5/ext/hash  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/php_http.c -o php_http.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootcjY5MM/pecl_http-2.0.4/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php5/ext/hash -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/php_http.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_http.o
In file included from /usr/include/php5/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27:0,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/php_http_api.h:29,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/php_http.c:13:
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [php_http.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Funny you should mention that, I just dealt with the same thing a few hours ago. You will have to install one more dependency, `libpcre3-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

Comment: :D thank you very much :) it installled but i still cant install the id3 package its say 
   sudo pecl install id3
   downloading id3-0.2.tgz ...
   Starting to download id3-0.2.tgz (20,693 bytes)
   .....done: 20,693 bytes
   4 source files, building
   running: phpize
   Cannot find config.m4.
   Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

   If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev packageYou can do it by running 'apt-get install   php5-dev' as a root userERROR: `phpize' failed

Comment: So `sudo apt-get install php5-dev` then: you did install all those packages as sudo didn't you?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes sir i did

Comment: I am getting the following error while installing
`pecl/pecl_http requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
pecl/raphf requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
pecl/propro requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
No valid packages found
install failed`